# Why the Player.gamesCompleted attribute is never updated?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a class for my program Fermi Pico Bagel to run on (Bagel), but my counter for number of games is not working correctly. When the user correctly guesses the secret number and is prompted to see if they would like to play again, and they choose to do so, the games completed still reads zero. Please help. Thanks!

The Bagels class is the one from which I run it (the first one printed on here) and the Player class is the one from which the player's stats are kept.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bagels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playAgain = "";
        int userGuess[];
        int numOfMoves = 0;
        int numOfGames = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Pico, Fermi, Bagel! Good luck.");
        Player user = new Player();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of digits to use: ");
        int numDigits = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || (user.getGamesCompleted() == 0) ) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter the player's name: ");    
            String playerName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println();
            user.setName(playerName);
            numOfGames++;
        }       

        do { 

            if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("p") || (user.getGamesCompleted() >= 1)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of digits to use: ");
            numDigits = keyboard.nextInt();

            }
            System.out
                    .println("Starting game #" + (user.getGamesCompleted()) + 1);
            boolean isCorrect;

            Engine e = new Engine();
            e.setNumDigits(numDigits);
            e.generateNewSecret();

            int[] secretNumber = e.getSecretNumber();

            for (int i = 0; i < secretNumber.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(secretNumber[i]);

            }

            do {
                numOfMoves = 0;
                String guess = user.askForGuess();
                userGuess = e.convertNumToDigitArray(guess);
                Validator check = new Validator();
                numOfMoves++;
                isCorrect = check.validateGuess(secretNumber, userGuess,
                        numDigits);

                if (isCorrect == true) {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You won in "
                            + numOfMoves + " moves");
                }
                    user.updateStats(numOfMoves);
                    System.out.println("Statistics for " + user.getName());
                    System.out.println("Games completed: "
                            + user.getGamesCompleted());
                    System.out.println("Number of digits: " + e.getNumDigits());
                    System.out.println("Fastest win: " + user.getFastestWin()
                            + " guesses");
                    System.out.println("p - Play again");
                    System.out.println("r - Reset game");
                    System.out.println("q - Quit");
                    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
                    playAgain = keyboard.next();

                    if (playAgain.equals("r")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (playAgain.equals("q")) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if (playAgain.equals("p")) {
                        numOfGames++;
                        break;
                    }       

            } while (isCorrect == false);
        } while (playAgain.equals("p") || playAgain.equals("r"));

    }
}




public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int fastestWin;
    private int gamesCompleted;
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // take the user's guess
    public String askForGuess() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        return guess;
    }

    // returns the name
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // returns the quickest amount of guesses the player has won in
    public int getFastestWin() {
        return this.fastestWin;
    }

    // returns how many games the user has won/played
    public int getGamesCompleted() {
        return this.gamesCompleted;
    }

    // sets the name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // updates the fastest win (if the amount of turns has decreased
    // and increases the number of games completed
    public void updateStats(int numberOfMovesTakenToWin) {
        if (this.gamesCompleted == 1) {
            this.fastestWin = numberOfMovesTakenToWin;
        } else {
            if (this.fastestWin > numberOfMovesTakenToWin) {
                this.fastestWin = numberOfMovesTakenToWin;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Anyone can view the history of the question at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29462890/revisions. Replacing it with a "deleted" message doesn't redact anything, and is only disruptive.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `gamesCompleted` belongs to the `Player` object. When the user chooses to play again you do:

```
numOfGames++;
```

But this increments the local variable `numOfGames`, which is not related to `gamesCompleted`. If you search for where you use `gamesCompleted` you will see that you never change its value.

You could write a method to increment the number of games completed by that user. And call it instead of doing `numOfGames++`.

Something like:

```
public void incrementGamesCompleted() {
    this.gamesCompleted++;
}
```